# Jquery cloned div not functioning like the original?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I clone a div on document load, which contains an input element with `id=taskInput`.

On pressing of the enter key, I replace the div with a dynamically created div. If the user then presses a delete button I replace this created div with the clone of the original.

My problem is that my document.queryselector is not working with the cloned version of the original. I want to have the same functionality as I originally had once the delete button is pressed.

```
var originalState = $("#inputContainer").clone(true)
```

```
document.querySelector('#taskInput').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  if((e.which == 13) && ( document.querySelector('#taskInput').value.length > 0 )){
    addButtons(this.value)
  } 
})
```

```
function addButtons(task){
  $("#inputContainer").replaceWith('<div id=taskConfirmed></div>')
}
```

```
$(document).on('click','#delete',function(){
  $("#taskConfirmed").replaceWith(originalState)
})
```

Comment: Is `#taskInput` Supossed to be `#taskConfirmed`?  It's hard to understand the flow with just these pieces.  I'm also uncertain if the jQuery clone method will duplicate event bindings not created through jQuery itself.  The issue may be that you are mixing jQuery bindings with vanilla JS bindings (addEventListener).

Comment: Can you put together a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue? Just a subset of your page's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to mix vanilla with the jQuery, just use the magic of jQuery to attach the `keypress` event will do the trick, like :

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#taskInput', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
    addButtons(this.value)
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var originalState = $("#inputContainer").clone(true);

$(document).on('keypress', '#taskInput', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
    addButtons(this.value)
  }
})

function addButtons(task) {
  $("#inputContainer").replaceWith('<div id=taskConfirmed>Task Confirmed</div>')
}

$(document).on('click', '#delete', function() {
  $("#taskConfirmed").replaceWith(originalState);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='inputContainer'>
  <input id="taskInput" />
</div>

<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, yeah i'll stick to jQuery throughout where possible

Answer (score 0):

The selector is not working anymore because when you cloned the element there was 2 elements with same ID. in this case you must clone then change the id attribute like this:

```
clonnedElement.attr('id','myClonedElement');
```

then the selector will work again